# Filtering an ObservableCollection with CollectionViewSource yields

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have an observable collection of objects that changes overtime.

```
ObservableCollection
    Object 1
    Object 2
    ...
```

What I'd like to do is display a filtered version of this information in a combo box. So I set up a CollectionViewSource whos source is the ObservableCollection. And who's filter I've defined:

```
private const string Unknown = "Unknown";
public DevicePackageInfo()
{
    this.operatingSystemVersion = DevicePackageInfo.Unknown;
    this.packageVersionInfo = new PackageVersionInfo(DevicePackageInfo.Unknown);
    this.PackageVersionList = new ObservableCollection<PackageVersionInfo>() { new PackageVersionInfo(DevicePackageInfo.Unknown) };
    this.packageVersionCollectionView = new CollectionViewSource();
    this.packageVersionCollectionView.Filter += PackageHistoryFilter;
    this.packageVersionCollectionView.Source = this.PackageVersionList;

    this.SetSynced();
}

public void PackageHistoryFilter(object sender, FilterEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item != null)
        e.Accepted = ((PackageVersionInfo)e.Item).OnEAC || ((PackageVersionInfo)e.Item).SelectedOnPC;
}
```

The problem is when I update the ObservableCollection my combo box does not update.

The only object I see in my list is "Unknown," the first object I add to my list during construction of the class.

My solution may not be exactly right... But I'm puzzled. Is there a built in way for a filtered collection source to subscribe from an `ObservableCollection` and stay up to date? How do I do this?

When I change my ObservableCollection I want to update the collection bound to my combo box.

Minimal code is ideal, I don't really want to define a new collection class that implements notifiable and the like.

EDIT: Here is my XAML

```
<ComboBox  Name="cbSelection" bhvr:SelectionChangedBehaviour.Command="{Binding PackageSelectionCommand}" ItemsSource="{Binding PackageInfo.PackageVersionCollectionView.View, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" SelectedItem="{Binding PackageInfo.PackageVersionInfo, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"  
                              IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True">
```

Comment: Normally when you use an ObservableCollection the CollectionViewSource gets updates automatically. I just tried it, and my ComboBox gets the new objects that I add to my ObservableCollection.

Comment: That's what I thought. I figured it out eventually. I had a lot of things being run off of raisepropertychanged and Update Handle etc... So I removed all of that and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this up so that people can get an idea of what the solution looks like:

```
public ObservableCollection<Tuple<String, String>> MyObservableCollection;
public CollectionViewSource MyCollectionViewSource { get; set; }

public PetViewModel()
{
    this.MyObservableCollection = new ObservableCollection<Tuple<String, String>>();
    this.MyCollectionViewSource = new CollectionViewSource();
    this.MyCollectionViewSource.Source = this.MyObservableCollection;
    this.MyCollectionViewSource.Filter += OnlyCatsFilter;

    this.MyObservableCollection.Add(new Tuple<string,string>("Paul", "Cat"));
    this.MyObservableCollection.Add(new Tuple<string,string>("Zoey", "Dog"));
    this.MyObservableCollection.Add(new Tuple<string,string>("Dude", "Turtle"));

    this.MyCollectionViewSource.View.Refresh();
}

public void OnlyCatsFilter(object sender, FilterEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item != null)
    {
        e.Accepted = (e.Item as Tuple<String, String>).Item2 == "Cat";
    }
}
```